The meaning of "chief among ten thousand"

My beloved is white and ruddy, chief among ten thousand (dagul me-revavah)"
(Song of Solomon 5:10. New King James Version)

Vast majority of translations don't use the word "chief" like in NKJV, but "outstanding", "distinguished", "notable" etc. So I think the meaning of the phrase is my beloved is unique among people. The word "revavah" (ten thousand) can be simply used for a great number (see Ezekiel 16:7)
But some commentators say it is talking about his armies or his camp:
"He is surrounded by many armies" (Rashi)
"Myriad holy ones are about Him" (Ezra ben Solomon)
'The chiefest among ten thousand - literally, "a bannered one among a myriad;" hence one signalized, a leader of ten thousand warriors" (Barnes Notes)
So what's its true meaning: he is chief of some group of people or he is unique among the people?

I added to my answer an explanation on the use of chief in the KJV.

As far as the meaning of chief in the KJV see:

And are built upon the foundation of the apostles and prophets, Jesus Christ himself being the chief corner stone;
(Eph 2:20)


This is a faithful saying, and worthy of all acceptation, that Christ Jesus came into the world to save sinners; of whom I am chief.
(1 Tim. 1:15)

Chief in the KJV can be used with the same meaning as modern translations translate Song of Solomons 5:10.  Search the word chief in the KJV.
You are correct that
דָּג֖וּל מֵרְבָבָֽה
goes together.
מֵרְבָבָֽה are common words, but
דָּג֖וּל
is not.  The context implies that the prefixed preposition
מֵ
conveys a comparative sense and means than or from with the comparative sense.

כִּ֤י טֹ֣וב סַ֭חְרָהּ מִסְּחַר־כָּ֑סֶף וּ֝מֵחָר֗וּץ תְּבוּאָתָֽהּ׃
(Prov. 3:14, BHS2003)

רב, הרכה
means a lot, and translators see 10,000 as a better understanding of its meaning in this type of context.
The meaning of
דָּג֖וּל
is not as certain, but note it is a qal passive participle masculine singular absolute.  The lexicons don't have a good consensus of its meaning and the active can have the meaning of deceive.  It does have the sense of appearance thus attractive, especially in this context.  One could say " more handsome than 10,ooo" or embed a comparative sense with:

distinguished among ten thousand. (ESV)


Outstanding among ten thousand (NASB1986)


notable among ten thousand (HCSV)


Preeminent among ten thousand (JPS1985)


The operative verb in the OP's question is דָּגַל (dagal) which appears only four times in the OT with the following meanings:

The fundamental meaning, according to BDB is


look, behold ... lifted up like a banner, or furnished with a banner,
i.e. exalted, distinguished ... looked at, conspicuous


Ps 20:5 - lift up banners
SS 5:10 - outstanding, distinguished, notable, conspicuous
SS 6:4 - like army with banners, ie, conspicuous
SS 6:10 - like an army with banners, ie, conspicuous

Its use in SS 5:10, especially in conjunction with "10,000" makes the most probable meaning "distinguished/conspicuous among 10,000" or similar.  The allusion to "banners" is what makes the subject conspicuous.
"Armies" and "banners" are not mentioned in the text but appear to be implied to make something "like an army with banners".
Thus, the sense in SS 5:10 appears to be that the beloved sees her lover as wonderfully distinguished among all her many acquaintances.

Taking a look at “A Comprehensive Etymological Dictionary Of The Hebrew Language” by Ernest Klein, p.114-115, we see:

Taking a snip from this we see the etymology of the Hebrew word “דֶּגֶל” (degel), which means “standard, banner, flag.” You'll notice that it suggests the word may be a loanword from Akkadian, where “diglu” (=eysight; sight, gaze), implying something that is conspicuous and is looked at. Rather fitting for the use of a banner as something that draws attention.


It possibly connects the Hebrew term with the Arabic word “ra’yah,” (=banner), which comes from “ra’ā(y)” (=he saw). Scholars also link it to the Arabic word “dajjālah,” (=a large crowd), and the Tigré word “dagal,” (=army).


Qal: “he set up a banner.”
Niph: “he gathered around the banners” or “was adorned.”
Pi: “he adorned/praised/glorified” or “he set up a banner.”
Hiph: “he praised/glorified” or “he decked out with flags.”
Hoph: Passive form, “was praised/glorified” or “it was decked out
with flags.”

